when load control register during in switching real mode to protect mode
The Intel SDM suggestion
From intel sdm 10.9.1 Switching to Protected Mode, it give following
steps:

...

Execute a MOV CR0 instruction that sets the PE flag (and optionally the PG    flag) in control register CR0.

Immediately following the MOV CR0 instruction, execute a far JMP or far CALL    instruction. (This operation is typically a far jump or
call to the next    instruction in the instruction stream.)

The JMP or CALL instruction immediately after the MOV CR0 instruction changes the flow of execution and
serializes the processor.


...

After entering protected mode, the segment registers continue to hold the    contents they had in real-address mode. The JMP or CALL
instruction in step    4 resets the CS register. Perform one of the
following operations to update    the contents of the remaining
segment registers.

Reload segment registers DS, SS, ES, FS, and GS. If the ES, FS,
and/or GS
registers are not going to be used, load them with a null selector. ...




This means that after we execute the MOV to CR0 (set PE) instruction, it is
best to execute a far jump or call immediately. After completing the above steps,
go to load control register
But on my own opinion,  after executing "MOV to CR0" (set PE), the CPU has
entered protected mode. At this time, executing MOV to SS, MOV to DS will also
successfully load the control register from the segment descriptor.
test
I wrote a small program and run it in qemu, part of it is as follows:
lgdt %cs:gdt_desc

mov $0x28, %eax
mov %eax, %es

mov $1, %eax
mov %eax, %cr0

mov $0x28, %eax
mov %eax, %es
ljmp $0x10, $.startup_prot

The above code modifies the ES selector before and after the mov to CR0 (set
PE) instruction. Debugging using qemu+gdb.

gdb print information

(gdb) ni
38          mov $0x28, %eax
(gdb) ni
39          mov %eax, %es
(gdb)
41          mov $1, %eax
(gdb) ni
42          mov %eax, %cr0
(gdb) ni
44          mov $0x28, %eax
(gdb) ni
45          mov %eax, %es
(gdb) ni
46          ljmp $0x10, $.startup_prot


When gdb is executed to position 39, use the qemu monitor info registers
command to obtain the ES register value:
ES =0028 00000280 0000ffff 00009300


When gdb is executed to position 46, use the qemu monitor info registers
command to obtain the ES register value:
ES =0028 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]



It can be found that after executing "MOV to CR0" (set PE), the relevant
instructions of the load control register can be executed successful.
So I want to ask, is it reasonable to execute the "load control register"
instruction immediately after MOV to CR0 (set PE), and what is the meaning of
step 5 in the manual?
Thanks

Was your documentation translated from a different language? I only mention it because point 5 usually reads (in English): The JMP or CALL instruction immediately after the MOV CR0 instruction changes the flow of execution and serializes the processor. That FAR JMP or all has the side effect of clearing the instruction pre-fetch queue. It is possible for the processor to decode real mode instructions after mov %eax, %cr0 but before it executes that instruction. You want to flush the prefetch queue so that the instructions after mov %eax, %cr0 are protected mode decodings.

A somewhat related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964347/why-should-prefetch-queue-be-invalidated-after-entering-protected-mode

@MichaelPetch Hi~ Michael
Thank you for your correction, it was my mistake. It has been corrected.
I noticed in the link you mentioned above that it says:
Instructions in the prefetch queue may also be predecoded so the jump may change the interpretation of the instructions.
Does this mean that after execute mov to CR0 (set PE), it is possible to use old
ES register for addressing (%edi) due to instruction prefetching when we execute
mov %eax, (%edi) ?
If the above is correct, then mov %eax, %es in this test will not be affected ?

Because mov %eax, %es instruction won't  access memory.
